# What to look for in wood selection when building a coffee table frame with glass top

Tags: hardwood, table

I'm looking to build a coffee table with a design similar to that in the picture. A simple frame, with a glass top. The other photo I've included is one of my floor, which might be teak (I rent, in the picture some untreated and treated, as we've had some water damage).

The table will be quite long, perhaps 160cm (63") in length, and maybe 50cm (20"). In order to support such a long stretch, I'll need to mind the wood selection.

- It will have to be a hardwood. Perhaps teak or ironwood? What would be able to support such a long stretch?
- Color-wise, I'm looking for something slightly lighter than the finished floor but lighter than what is used in the example photo.

I'd appreciate recommendations on what to look for in selecting the right kind of wood, and perhaps specific hardwood recommendations.

In addition, any comments on what to watch out for in building such a stretched coffee table.

[image: Example table]

[image: My wooden floor]

Answer (score 1):

Knowing if the wood is appropriate depends on a lot of factors, but if you're building something close to what's in the photo you might want to consider Beech (good indoor furniture wood). White Ash has more grain and color to it. Poplar can also work (and may be more readily available in local DIY/big box stores). It will depend somewhat on your locale to build something from what's readily available and suitable for the climate.

There's nothing overly complex with the coffee table as pictured. You will want to think about the joinery methods for the various pieces of the frame to be stable and rigid.